# Restaurar posicion inicial elemento "draggable" cuando el elemento es arrastrado a un lugar erróneo (no objetivo)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Estoy tratando de usar un codigo del que ya se hablo hace tiempo en estos foros

http://jsfiddle.net/fsy37kv4/

Me gustaría que cuando un circulo fuera arrastrado a una posición erronea, el circulo retornara a su posición inicial.

Mi problema es que yo lo que quiero es que cuando arrastre el circulo de su posición inicial a su posición final, desaparezca cuando llegue a su posición final (esto esta OK) pero en cambio cuando lo arrastre a un lugar erroneo, retorne a su posición inicial.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    var el = ev.target;
    var parent = el.getAttribute("data-parent");
    
    if(!parent){
        el.setAttribute("data-parent", el.parentNode.id);
    }
    
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", el.id);
    
    
    
        
    setTimeout(() => {
        ev.target.classList.add('hide'); //Ocultamos el elemento al arrastrar , hay que definir la clase .hide en el css de la pagina
    }, 0);
    
    
}

function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); 
    
    
    
    ev.target.classList.remove('drag-over');
    
        // get the draggable element
    const id = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    const draggable = document.getElementById(id);

    // add it to the drop target
    ev.target.appendChild(draggable);

    // display the draggable element
    draggable.classList.remove('hide'); 
    
    
}

function dragEnd(ev){
    if(ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect == "none"){
         var parent = document.getElementById(ev.target.getAttribute("data-parent"));
        
        parent.appendChild(ev.target);
    }
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 50px
}
.hide {
  display: none;
  }
  
.drop {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#bracelet {
    width:420px;
    height:75px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="bracelet">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="div2" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg" ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div3" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div4" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag3" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div5" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag4" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div6" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag5" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div7" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag6" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div8" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag7" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div9" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag8" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div10" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag9" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div11" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag10" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div12" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag11" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div13" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag12" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar la lógica para decidir cuándo la posición de destino es correcta o no?

Comment: Buenas la posición de destino válida es cualquiera de los div ya que tienen todos la propiedad drop da igual la que sea. La invalida por tanto es cualquier lugar fuera de esas cajas